# HTML and Javascript form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I am very new in javascript and have a task to create something like this
[image]

When i input "something" in text area it will create "something" text in the bottom of button.
And when i input it again, it will create the text in bottom or upper the previous text. like

Something 2

Something 1

Help please..

Comment: This is a good question, but you need to show some effort yourself before you can get help here.

Comment: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="asd" >
  <textarea name="text" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("something");
</script>

how to write in the bottom without deleting the form?

Comment: i create form and submit button, but i dont know how to make it appear in bottom. i just make it show but the form gone,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/p7dVa/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
<textarea id='txt'></textarea>
<div id='contents'></div>
<button type='button' onclick="add()">Enter</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function add(){
var txt= document.getElementById('txt').value;
var content= document.getElementById('contents');
content.innerHTML+='<span>'+txt+'</span><br/>'
}
```

Comment: Why isn't 'container' closed? Also shouldn't < and > be escaped?

Comment: @username it works fine, check the fiddle. closing was a formatting prob

Comment: thanks for the answer, it open my mind quite a lot.
i swap the place for contents to make the text appear after the button.
but what if i want to make the new textarea's value upper than the older one?

Comment: @Scramble check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/p7dVa/4/
you might want to accept the answer if it helped you..

Comment: Linefeeds might be a problem (if you want them) ... May I propose my solution ? http://jsfiddle.net/p7dVa/5/